# How/where do I configure jboss as 7 so that I do not have to redeploy my .war file everytime I modify a JSP?

Tags: jsp, jboss, jboss7.x

How/where do I configure jboss as 7 so that I do not have to redeploy my .war file everytime I modify a JSP? It is much more time consuming to have to undeploy and redeploy my .war file every time. how do i fix this?

Comment: In standalone.xml the following nees to be added under <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">:

    <configuration>
        <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
    </configuration>

So it should look like:

    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
        ...
      <configuration>
        <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
      </configuration>
    </subsystem>

Comment: What you're trying to do is not a fix, you're trying to find a workaround. Fixing JSP code during runtime leads to disaster...

Comment: I think he's just developing jsp code but doing it during the build process. I'm curious how this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploded deployment instead of deploying as a war file. That way you can change your jsp files and they will be reloaded when modified.